# java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name, com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I got many crashes from my app which include **GCM(Google Notification)** feature.
The crash detail as below:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package
>   name'com.mypackagename'.-android.os.Parcel.readException(1465)
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(1419)
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs$zza$zza.zza(-1)
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs$zza$zza.zza(-1)
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj.zza(-1)
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzf.zza(-1)
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzh.zzqL(-1)
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(-1)
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzw(-1)
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqN(-1)
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(-1)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(110) android.os.Looper.loop(193)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(5292)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(-2)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(515)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(828)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(644)
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(-2)

[The same issue:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230497](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230497)

Comment: Check your package name, the error is on ur name of package check and correct

Comment: @W4R10CK Thanks, the crash information come from production environments the package name is correct in online app. **com.mypackagename** is replace one.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292058/receiving-error-when-trying-to-connect-with-google-awareness-services) if it can help you.

Comment: @KENdi Thanks for your comments , My issue is that I got many crash from online app, but all the many crash from my app just a part of android device.

Comment: I can't figure out a way to reproduce this issue, but I'm seeing it as well in Crashlytics.

Comment: @TimNuwin , Hi Tim, me too. I have contacted with Google player support which need I give a crash report or screen shot as proof. because I got the issue from my self implements UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: hi did you find a valid solution for this issue? thanks.

Comment: @savepopulation, the issue disappeared after i feedback to google player team. and I think that the issue is from google player. mybe you can try it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**The solution:**

> feedback the issue to google player support and than the issue will disppear.

or

update the SDK of com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm to latest version

Comment: Where does one file Google Play Services bugs at?

Comment: What do you mean by "feedback the issue"?What were the steps you took to fix the issue?

Comment: @kos just feedback the issue to google play support team

Comment: @kos you can try to update the sdk to latest version too. com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:latestversion-number

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

> 1. Check Permissions:

Ensure that you have INTERNET permission, add this line to `androidManifes.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> 2. Update Google Play Services:

Ensure that the Google Play Services library in your app is up-to-date. You can do this by updating the dependencies in your build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.0.0'
```

you can check [play-servies latest version here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)