# Google Wallet API java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, kotlin, google-wallet

I am integrating with Google Pay API by referring sample from https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart
It was working on my android 10 devices.
But when I do the testing with android 9, and google play services version 23.48.16. I got this error.

My device is Galaxy Note8 with android 9.
Is it the issue from version of google play service? Thank for your support in advance.

```
2023-12-28 17:01:24.633 16055-16055 AndroidRuntime          com...le.android.gms.samples.wallet  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.google.android.gms.samples.wallet, PID: 16055
                                                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
                                                                                                        at m.azi.q(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@234816022@23.48.16 (100400-0):172)
                                                                                                        at m.azf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@234816022@23.48.16 (100400-0):14)
                                                                                                        at m.azh.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@234816022@23.48.16 (100400-0):7)
                                                                                                        at m.aza.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@234816022@23.48.16 (100400-0):7)
                                                                                                        at m.azb.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@234816022@23.48.16 (100400-0):281)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

I tried to search around but not found solution yet. Also reset the google play service to older version 19.x.x, the crash is gone but the app still requires update google play services to be able use the features. After upgrade google play service to 23.48.16, I got the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name, com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690720/java-lang-securityexception-unknown-calling-package-name-com-google-android-gm)