KMM error: java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'
Any idea how to solve this error using Firebase Auth:
suspend fun createNewUser(user: UserInfo, password: String) {
     val userCredential = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, password)
    }

Failed to get service from broker. 
java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3069)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
at angb.a(:com.google.android.gms@244337029@24.43.37 (190400-693941914):36)
at anei.z(:com.google.android.gms@244337029@24.43.37 (190400-693941914):143)
at amln.run(:com.google.android.gms@244337029@24.43.37 (190400-693941914):54)

The versions that I use for my KMM app:
gradle project:
dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2")
    }   

plugins {
  id("com.android.application").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
  id("com.android.library").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
  kotlin("android").version("1.9.0").apply(false)
  kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.7.20").apply(false)

  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.9.0"
}

gradle shared:
implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-firestore:1.10.4")
implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-common:1.10.4")
implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-auth:1.10.4")

The user gets created but my app crashes because of the error.
Have a great day!

the question is short detail. give more detail about config, implement

done, any idea ?

Does this issue like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690720/java-lang-securityexception-unknown-calling-package-name-com-google-android-gm

Yes, I have tried, but I got the same error.

As you see the error "... package name ...". It looks like the package name you define related to Firebase, might be incorrect, either env. product or env. debug. Your question need to explore it. Or you can follow other question with high watching rating, comment or do something for people to help you.

I am using la latest package...

Sr, i mean i'm not sure that the package name of your project does not map with package name at Firebase Cloud. Since you does not explore package name of your project.

I checked the names, it is correct...
